# AdaptiveCard 1.3 version

Tags: json, botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I would like to confirm if the adaptive card 1.3 version has already been released?
I tried to implement the new features on our project, i updated the json file and changed the version to 1.3 and followed what the features presented on this video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEsjrFIf110&t=387s but I wasn't able to replicate almost all of the feature except 1 the Full Width Card. I have already updated the adaptive card nugget package to 2.6.0. I tried also to replicate those features in adaptive designer https://adaptivecardsci.z5.web.core.windows.net/pr/4894/designer . I got the label feature working there but it did not work on our case. here is the json that i have created :
(ignore the double quotes as i have store the json inside a variable. I am using adaptivecardtemplate to render the string below).

```
{
    ""type"": ""AdaptiveCard"",
    ""$schema"": ""http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"",
    ""version"": ""1.3"",
    ""body"": [
        {
                   ""type"": ""Container"",
                   ""items"":[
                        {
                            ""type"": ""TextBlock"",
                            ""text"": ""Full Width card"",
                            ""size"": ""Large"",
                            ""weight"": ""Bolder""
                        }
                    ]
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""Input.ChoiceSet"",
            ""id"": ""temperature"",
            ""label"": ""How would you like your burger prepared?"",
            ""isRequired"": true,
            ""errorMessage"" : ""Please select one of the above options"",
            ""choices"":
            [
                {
                    ""title"": ""Rare"",
                    ""value"": ""Rare"",
                },
                {
                    ""title"": ""Medium"",
                    ""value"": ""Medium"",
                },
                {
                    ""title"": ""Medium"",
                    ""value"": ""Medium"",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""Input.ChoiceSet"",
            ""id"": ""selectedUser"",
            ""label"": ""How would you like your burger prepared?"",
            ""isRequired"": true,
            ""errorMessage"" : ""Please select one of the above options"",
            ""choices"":
            [
                {
                    ""title"": ""Static 1"",
                    ""value"": ""Static 1"",
                }

            ],
            ""choices.data"":{
                ""type"": ""Data.Query"",
                ""dataset"": ""graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users""
            }

        },
        {
            ""type"": ""Input.ChoiceSet"",
            ""placeholder"": ""Static AutoComplete"",
            ""style"": ""filtered"",
            ""isMultiSelect"": false,
            ""id"" : ""choiceRestaurant"",
            ""choices"":
            [
                {
                    ""title"": ""Static 1"",
                    ""value"": ""Static 1"",
                },
                {
                    ""title"": ""Static 1"",
                    ""value"": ""Static 1"",
                },
                {
                    ""title"": ""Static 1"",
                    ""value"": ""Static 1"",
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""ActionSet"",
            ""actions"": [
                {
                    ""type"": ""Action.Submit"",
                    ""title"": ""Action.Submit"",
                    ""mode"": ""secondary""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    ""actions"":[
        {
            ""type"": ""Action.Submit"",
            ""title"": ""Button""
        }
    ],
    ""msteams"": {
        ""width"": ""Full""
    }
}
```

If you guys have any ideas how to replicate the new features it would be very helpful to me.
they stated in the video that these features are already in a dev preview version. do you know where to find that version? is there some configuration that I missed?

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have left out a lot of details about your project. Where are you trying to render these Adaptive Cards? I see you used the [tag:botframework] tag. Do you have a bot? Where did you get this Adaptive Cards designer link? https://adaptivecardsci.z5.web.core.windows.net/pr/4894/designer Why aren't you using the normal Adaptive Cards website? https://adaptivecards.io/designer/

Comment: well i render these adaptive cards using adaptivecardtemplate. everything works fine, i was able to return the adaptive cards and i have a bot already working. I just want to import the new updates on adaptive cards to the project i am currently working on like on the youtube link i posted above. They said that the adaptivecard 1.3 is already up but i dont actually replicate the new features when i followed the video. Even though i have updated the adaptive card nuget to 2.6.0.
with regards to the website i think i made a mistake on that one i meant adaptivecards.io/designer. thanks.

Comment: Would you kindly answer my first two questions?

Comment: Here is what i used to render the template above
var cardTemplate = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(cardTemplateJson);
            var card = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdaptiveCard>(cardTemplate.Expand(responseJson));
            var attachment = new Attachment { ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType, Content = card };
            var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachment);

cardTemplate: this is the json string from above
responseJson = the jobject i sent to expand the cardtemplate. so i can use a variable inside the template.

Comment: Do you have a bot?
- Yes i have a bot and it is already working. I am just looking for a way to reflect the latest features in adaptivecard 1.3 .

Comment: I asked you where you're trying to render the cards. You're asking about whether Adaptive Cards 1.3 is supported but you haven't even told us what renderer you're using. If you have a Bot Framework bot then you must be using some kind of chat platform where you expect these cards to be rendered. Why haven't you told us what it is?

Comment: My apologies, yes i used bot framework. the bot will return that card. if i chat a certain command to the bot. 
I installed the bot in microsoft teams for a tenant.

Comment: Okay, "Teams" is the relevant piece of information that you should've included in your question. Teams is the thing you're expecting to render the card, so the question of whether a certain version of Adaptive Cards is supported depends entirely on Teams. We could not possibly help you until you gave us this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this document to see which versions of Adaptive Cards are supported on each platform: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/resources/partners

You may notice that Teams still only supports Adaptive Cards 1.2:

[image]

It doesn't matter what versions of Adaptive Cards have been "released." All that matters is what version of Adaptive Cards your platform is using. If Teams is using Adaptive Cards 1.2 then there's no way it could access features of Adaptive Cards 1.3, regardless of whether Adaptive Cards 1.3 has been released. I highly recommend reading my blog post to gain a better understanding of Adaptive Cards: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Comment: Hi kyle, Thanks for the info.
i could not do anything for now right? since ms teams only support 1.2.

Comment: You could give feedback to Teams asking them to upgrade Adaptive Cards, but otherwise yes you have no control over the Teams renderer. Is this answer acceptable?

Comment: hey kyle. thank you for the response. 
i was just wondering why the full width is working on teams when the full width feature is included in the adaptive card 1.3 version. and it is working on my end . except the other features.
i tried all the features but the full width card is the only feature that is working.
i am assuming that the feature(full width) is already added in v 1.2? which the teams is currently supporting? 
can you clarify me on this? Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the full width feature. I've never seen that before